# Error using Ruby 'pp' pretty printer (variable needed in a metaprogramming test)

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am playing with DSL metaprogramming in Ruby.

The following program works as expected, using nested blocks evaluations; its meaning is not important for the problem I expose here. The 'bug' or trouble I have concerns the four last lines:

```
# works (using a variable 'mm' to store the result of Gen.define method)
mm=Gen.define("abc") do
  node(:func){}
end
pp mm
# returns {"abc"=>#<Definition:0x000000021f6c90 @nodes={:func=>#<Node:0x000000021f6a60 @name=:func>}>}
```

but the following does not work, returning an error, also shown below. The difference is that the result of define (a hash) is here *directly* passed as argument to 'pp' pretty printer, while the working program used a variable (mm).

```
# does NOT work (no variable)
pp Gen.define("abc") do
  node(:func){}
end
```

Why such a difference in the behavior?

The error is:

> `instance_eval': block not supplied (ArgumentError)

Here is the full (working) program (again it does not do anything usefull).

```
require 'pp'

class Gen
  def self.define name,&block
    @nodes=Definition.new(&block)
    return name => @nodes
  end
end

class Definition
  def initialize(&block)
    @nodes={}
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def node name,&block
    @nodes.merge!(name =>  Node.new(name,&block))
  end
end

class Node
  def initialize name,&block
    @name=name
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

mm=Gen.define("abc") do
  node(:func){}
end

pp mm
```

Comment: look up operator precedence in ruby, the `do` operator passes the following block to the outermost function (in your case `pp`), either use parentheses or the alternative block syntax (`{ }`)

Comment: that was the needed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is just precedence: when you say

```
pp Gen.define("abc") do
  node(:func){}
end
```

it's `pp` that gets the block. That's the same as:

```
pp(Gen.define("abc")) do
  node(:func){}
end
```

This will do what you want:

```
pp(Gen.define("abc") do
  node(:func){}
end)
```

Some people (including me) recommend using braces instead of `do`…`end` for a block when the method returns a value. You'll probably find this gives you a less surprising result:

```
pp Gen.define("abc") {
  node(:func){}
}
```